# I can't modify an array through jquery json parsing

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

```
questions = new Array();

$.getJSON('questions.php', function(data){
    $.each(data , function(i,jsonData) {
        questions[1] = "hey";
    });
});

alert(questions[1]);
```

here's the code. And it's not working, gives me an "undefined". I don't understand why.

Comment: AJAX means asynchronous.

Comment: Use array literals, not `new Array()`.

Comment: @minitech, won't change a thing, though I like that syntax too.

Comment: @gdoron: It’s a comment :P

Comment: @dfsq if oyu want to post an answer I'll check it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical use case for callback functions. Consider the following example:

```
function getQuestions(callback) {
    $.getJSON('questions.php', function(data){
        $.each(data , function(i,jsonData) {
            questions[1] = "hey";
        });
        callback(questions);
    });
}

getQuestions(function(data) {
    alert(data[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "questions" array is not being set to anything hence the "undefined". Add the alert code inside the callback function there or call a function to alert the user.